# PHP Commenting - Forgot some stuff!

Tags: php

maybe this is a very simple question, but forgot the answer about it because I had it once XD

So the question is about php comments, when commenting functions you use @param to explain what? Can you please clear me up?

Comment: for more information on how to actively participate, please see the FAQ:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: see the phpdoc documentation online!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You document what types of arguments the function takes and their names. It's used by automatic documentation generators.

See http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.param.pkg.html.

Answer (score 0):

`@param` is used when documenting your code.  It is so that automated documentation generators know what to output.  You specify function parameter names and types, as well as a description.

Like this:

`@param datatype $paramname description`

All you need to know can be found here:  http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.param.pkg.html